Upgrading Storybook from 7.5.3 to 8.x.x while keeping react version 16.x.x, storybook works but have issue with testing
Running unit test on the story throws following error
Cannot find module 'react-dom/client' from '../../../common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/@storybook+react-dom-shim@8.0.0_react-dom@16.13.1_react@16.13.1/node_modules/@storybook/react-dom-shim/dist/react-18.js'
Why is storybook going through react-16.js but running unit test using react/testing-library on the same story going through react-18.js?
Basically have no clue on what's going on
